# Hide windows in current desktop (Lion)

Tags: macos, applescript, spaces, desktop

I'd like to make a keyboard shortcut that hides all windows on the current desktop, while ignoring windows on other desktops. Is this possible using Applescript?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion (Works on OSX 10.8)

Using Automator :

- Create a new Service with automator
- Select *Service receives selected **no input** in **any application***
- Add a **Run AppleScript** action

Copy this script :

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "System Events"
        set processList to (every application process whose visible is true)        
        repeat with appProc in processList
            set windowList to every window of appProc
            repeat with aWindow in windowList
                click (third button of aWindow)
            end repeat
        end repeat
    end tell
end run
```

- Save your new service
- In System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services add a keyboard shortcut to your news ervice

Edit :

Other script :

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Finder"
        set visible of every process whose visible is true and name is not "Finder" to false
        close every window
    end tell
end run
```

It hides all apps but it **closes** all finder windows.

Comment: So does this work because only the buttons of windows in the current desktop are clickable? Ideally I'd like the windows to be hidden instead of minimized, ie visible = false.

Comment: You can't hide a window but you can hide an app. And hiding a app = hiding its windows in every space.

Comment: That's fine, I don't have any app windows on multiple desktops. Sorry my terminology is wrong/misleading

Comment: See my edit, I proposed an other script

Comment: I started with something very similar, but it hides all apps on all desktops/spaces instead of just the current one. I'm not sure it's possible to do what I want to do :/